# Responsive menu - width auto and float left

Tags: html, css, css-float, width

I have a menu with the following CSS:

```
.nav {
    position: static; 
    text-align: left; 
    min-width: 300px;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 75%;
    margin-top: 3%; 
    padding-bottom: 5%;  
    float: left;
}
```

Menu's HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li><a href="ucp.php">Menu</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="blah.php">Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="purchase.php">Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/tz720k1h/1/)**

Next to it (on the right side) I have a form. I'm trying to make this responsive so when a user with lower resolution opens my site, the menu won't be on side, but on top, centered with 75% width. As you can see above, i've tried to do that using width: auto and min-width + max-width, but it refuses to work with float: left; for some reason. Putting images below for better understanding.

[My site on smaller resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4V7SV.png)

[How I want it to be on smaller resolution (changed width: auto to width:75%)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhEKG.png)

Seems like the float:left is making me problems here, because when I just remove that, width: auto works perfectly (however i need it so the form is aligned properly with the menu).

Thanks in advance for all the answers!

Comment: That may be true, but why would you make your would-be helpers go out and find it? Demo added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your styles in a media query to restrict them to the XS size range, and adjust like so:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .nav {
        position: static;
        text-align: left;
        min-width: 300px;
        width: 75%;
        max-width: 75%;
        margin: 3% auto 0;
    }
}
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/tz720k1h/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

I'd made some changes to your code..

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
  <li><a href="ucp.php">Menu</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="blah.php">Menu</a></li>
  <li><a href="purchase.php">Menu</a></li>
  <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
<form>
```

What you need to use is Media Query
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

```
.nav {
  position: static;
  text-align: left;
  min-width: 300px;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 75%;
  margin-top: 3%;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
  float: left;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .nav {
    position: center;
    text-align: left;
    min-width: 300px;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 80%;
    margin-top: 3%;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
    float: none;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left: 40px;
  }
}
```

DEMO:https://jsfiddle.net/tz720k1h/5/